# How to find a columns set for a primary key candidate in CSV file?

Tags: python, sql, algorithm, pandas

I have a CSV file (not normalized, example, real file up to 100 columns):

```
   ID, CUST_NAME, CLIENT_NAME, PAYMENT_NUM, START_DATE, END_DATE
    1,     CUST1,     CLIENT1,          10, 2018-04-01, 2018-04-02
    2,     CUST1,     CLIENT1,          10, 2018-04-01, 2018-05-30
    3,     CUST1,     CLIENT1,         101, 2018-04-02, 2018-04-03
    4,     CUST2,     CLIENT1,         102, 2018-04-02, 2018-04-03
```

How can I find ALL possible sets of columns which could be used as Primary key.

**Desired output:**

```
  1) ID
  2) PAYMENT_NUM,START_DATE,END_DATE
  3) CUST_NAME, CLIENT_NAME, PAYMENT_NUM,START_DATE,END_DATE
```

*I could do it in Java but may be Python/Pandas already provides a quick solution*

Comment: I think an example CSV and output might be useful here.

Comment: Any CSV file with more than 3 columns will fit

Comment: @gmlvsv - What is expected output?

Comment: @jezrael columns sets list like in question after 'Desired output:'

Comment: @gmlvsv - I think what rows with input data, I think [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) should help here.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

pandas and itertools will give you what you're looking for.

```
import pandas
from itertools import chain, combinations

def key_options(items):
    return chain.from_iterable(combinations(items, r) for r in range(1, len(items)+1) )

df = pandas.read_csv('test.csv');

# iterate over all combos of headings, excluding ID for brevity
for candidate in key_options(list(df)[1:]):
    deduped = df.drop_duplicates(candidate)

    if len(deduped.index) == len(df.index):
        print ','.join(candidate)
```

This gives you the output:

```
PAYMENT_NUM, END_DATE
CUST_NAME, CLIENT_NAME, END_DATE
CUST_NAME, PAYMENT_NUM, END_DATE
CLIENT_NAME, PAYMENT_NUM, END_DATE
PAYMENT_NUM, START_DATE, END_DATE
CUST_NAME, CLIENT_NAME, PAYMENT_NUM, END_DATE
CUST_NAME, CLIENT_NAME, START_DATE, END_DATE
CUST_NAME, PAYMENT_NUM, START_DATE, END_DATE
CLIENT_NAME, PAYMENT_NUM, START_DATE, END_DATE
CUST_NAME, CLIENT_NAME, PAYMENT_NUM, START_DATE, END_DATE
```

Comment: Thanks! why there is no one filed(ID) variant?

Comment: Because the ID is suitable on its own, it means every combination containing the ID is also suitable. That didn't seem like useful output. You can include it again by dropping `[1:]` from the `for` loop.

Answer (score 1):

This is one way via `itertools.combinations`. It works by, for each set of columns, dropping duplicates and checking if the size of the dataframe changes.

This results in 44 distinct combinations of columns.

```
from itertools import combinations, chain

full_list = chain.from_iterable(combinations(df, i) for i in range(1, len(df.columns)+1))

n = len(df.index)

res = []
for cols in full_list:
    cols = list(cols)
    if len(df[cols].drop_duplicates().index) == n:
        res.append(cols)

print(len(res))  # 44
```