# The fastest way to find primary key candidates in CSV file?

Tags: python, pandas, primary-key

**Find the primary key candidates in CSV file,** the test requires the nums of column <= 4 and any subset of these columns cannot be a primary key.
There are some example:

- key1: [column18] ==>correct
- key2: [column15,column18] ==>wrong, contains key1
- key3: [column1,column2,column3,column5,column6] ==> wrong, more than 4

This is a test for me! I have finished it in **35 seconds**, but not reach the efficient requirement: find primary keys in about **1 second** in a csv file about 10000 lines.

**Test Data:**

- [you can get the example csv file here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1j-u5IGGPb090gSa2SxgYwD8Af6WTEtGq).
- The right answer of this file is:
  [['column8', 'column11', 'column15', 'column18']]

So, my question is **"Is there any more efficient way to find primary keys?"**

**Here is my code:**

```
# coding: utf-8
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import os
import itertools
import time

def is_subkey(newkey,keys):
#     test wheather newkey is sub set of any keys
    for key in keys:
        if set(key).issubset(newkey):
            return True
    return False

def primarykey_recognition(file,max_num=4):
#     file is an file object, returnd by function open()
#   doc is a pandas DF
    doc = pd.read_csv(file,sep=',')
    num = 1
    result = []
    table_length = len(doc.values)
    while num <= max_num:
        keys = list(itertools.combinations(doc.columns,num))
#         print(keys)
        for key in keys:
            if is_subkey(key,result):
#           if key belong to any sub set of keys in result ,continue
                continue
#           
            bools = np.array(doc.duplicated(subset=list(key)))
            if np.sum(bools) > 0:
#           sum(bools) means bools has duplicated lines 
                continue
            else:
                result.append(list(key))
        num += 1
    return result

if __name__=="__main__":

    with open(r"..\data\Table_C.csv") as file:
        tic = time.clock()
        keys = primarykey_recognition(file)
        toc = time.clock()

        print("File {} has primary keys: ".format(filename))
        print(keys)
        print("Elapsed: {} s".format(round(toc - tic,4)))
```

I find there is a similar question ,[How to find a columns set for a primary key candidate in CSV file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49998457/how-to-find-a-columns-set-for-a-primary-key-candidate-in-csv-file), but the code is **not efficient** and find wrong keys like example key2.

**Here is the code of that question:**

```
# coding: utf-8
import pandas
from itertools import chain, combinations
import time

def key_options(items):
    return chain.from_iterable(combinations(items, r) for r in range(1, len(items)+1) )

tic = time.clock()    
df = pandas.read_csv(r"..\data\Table_C.csv");

# iterate over all combos of headings, excluding ID for brevity
for candidate in key_options(list(df)[1:]):
    deduped = df.drop_duplicates(candidate)

    if len(deduped.index) == len(df.index):
        print(','.join(candidate))

toc = time.clock()
print("Elapsed: {} s".format(round(toc - tic,4)))
```

Comment: Perhaps you could show an example?

Comment: @RoadRunner I have attached my csv file above. https://drive.google.com/open?id=1j-u5IGGPb090gSa2SxgYwD8Af6WTEtGq

Comment: @LIKe what do the true and false values in the CSV represent? Can one only use a column as part of a primary key for a row if that column's value is TRUE for that row? What do the numbers signify in this table? Is there a link to a formal write-up of the challenge? This expression of the puzzle is not quite clear.

Comment: @duhaime As I read the problem they are supposed to find all [candidate keys](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Candidate_key) of length <= 4. That is, columns that uniquely identify any row. I don't think the columns should be considered typed. "TRUE", "FALSE" and "-2" are just values.

Comment: @EmilVikström that sounds good. Why do the row values matter in that case? Isn't it enough just to know how many rows there are?

Comment: @duhaime Your result seems not like what I want to get. The  column number of each primary key don't have to be exactly equal to 4. Every primary key need to mark every row uniquely. The p-keys may contains 1, 2, 3, or 4 columns.

Comment: Like exactly, and all my primary keys contain 4 columns (as this eliminates the probability of one primary key being a subset of another). Is my solution *wrong* or do you have an aesthetic preference for some other algorithm? This whole question is quite unclear.

Comment: @duhaime I'm not sure whether your answer is right or not. because the result looks strange. defaultdict(<function nest at 0x0000022A288BC378>, {1: [2, 5, 7, 10], 2: [0, 9, 10, 12], 3: [3, 4, 5, 9], 4: [0, 4, 5, 7], 5: [1, 6, 9, 10], 6: [4, 6, 13, 14], 7: [1, 2, 4, 5], 8: [4, 10, 14, 19], 9: [2, 4, 5, 6], 10: [1, 3, 5, 6], 11: [0, 3, 5, 10], 12: [0, 1, 3, 7], 13: [1, 4, 6, 7], 14: [2, 3, 6, 9], 15: [1, 3, 4, 5], 16: [2, 9, 10, 13], 17: [0, 3, 4, 5], 18: [2, 3, 6, 7], 19: [1, 6, 13, 17], ... ... a very loooong dict. The correct answer is just one key contains four columns in this case.

Comment: @duhaime I have update the question, and add the correct result. I don't mind you    use number to represent column names. It's just because your result is too many and hard to understand. Do you mean every value in your result row_to_key is a primary key? please give some explanations of your code, thank you!

Comment: @LIKe thanks for following up. I updated my response so that we print the columns that uniquely identify each row. If you run the code, you should see output like the sample I provide below -- that output indicates the column indices that uniquely identify each row index. The code runs in ~linear time. Does this make sense?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are some ideas:

- Count the number of unique values for each column. Call these numbers u_1, u_2, ... Remove/skip combinations where multiplying these numbers result in a product < number of rows in the file. In your example file this will effectively remove almost all combinations because only boolean columns can at most identify 2*2*2*2 = 16 distinct values.
- Do not convert your candidates to sets. You only need to check for subsequences, not subsets. Do that linearly without creating new datastructures. Copying memory is expensive. Set intersection operations are also expensive.
- Profile your code with cProfile. Something like this: `python3 -m cProfile -s cumtime key-extractifyer.py  < lotsadata.csv`
- Reconsider if you really need numpy for this problem. Python lists have constant-time or amortized constant-time run-time for most operations already.

---

To clarify the first point:

Let us start on an abstract level. You are trying to find combinations of columns that satisfy some constraint. In this kind of problem we call all candidates the "[search space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feasible_region)" and each [candidate that satisfy the constraints](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feasible_region#Candidate_solution) are called a "solution to the problem". Right now your search space is "all combinations generated by itertools.combinations". You are checking your constraints against each candidate.

Now let us assume that checking the constraints is expensive. In your case that is the `pandas.duplicated()` call, which stands for 95% of your execution time. Clearly we can save a lot of time if we can minimize the search space!

Minimizing the search space can be done in three ways:

1. Find an algorithm for generating candidates that gives fewer false positives. I will leave this as an exercise if you really need to.
2. Find faster ways to exclude candidates that does not satisfy the constraints. This is what my first point is doing.
3. Find some hidden structure to the problem that allows you to exclude large parts of the search space at the same time. Example: if columns A, B, C, D is not a primary key you can also exclude all shorter combinations of these columns. You may be able to find a datastructure that allows you to do this kind of "sweeping removals".

I focus on "way 2", but feel free to explore the other ways as well if you need to.

A huge part of your search space are columns with binary values. In addition to that you have some columns with only a single value in them. For mathematical reasons combinations that does ONLY involve these columns can never satisfy your constraint (such combinations will never be solutions to your problem). One column that can have 2 values will at most be able to uniquely identify 2 rows. If you have 3 or more rows there must be at least two rows that share the same value in the column. This is called the [pigeonhole principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pigeonhole_principle).

We can scale this to more columns. Two binary columns can at most identify 2*2 = 4 rows, with these combinations: `(0, 0), (0, 1), (1, 0), (1, 1)`. And it scales to columns with more (or less) than two values. Two columns with 3 unique values in each can at most identify 3*3 = 9 rows.

This is the principle that we want to exploit to reduce the search space. By counting the number of *unique/distinct* values in each column at the start, and saving the results to an array so you don't have to do it on every loop iteration, you can give an upper bound on how many rows that column will be able to identify - AT MOST. So before you do the expensive `pandas.duplicated()` call, you check the cheaper multiplication to see if there is any chance that this column combination will be able to satisfy the constraints. If it is not, we can avoid the expensive call. Note that we are not trying to prove that your candidate *is* a solution, we are trying to prove that it *is not*. You will still need to do the expensive call before you know for certain, but on significantly fewer candidates.

Comment: According to your third suggestion, I tested the runtime of the .py file. I found that the most time-consuming is ```pandas.duplicated()```, 37s/(39s in total), and ```numpy``` is 1.7s.
So I considered implementing your first suggestion, but I don't quite understand this point. Can you explain the first point in detail? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I'm still not sure I understand the problem clearly, but the following maps each row number to a list of column indices by which it can be uniquely identified, and runs in ~0m0.145s:

```
from collections import defaultdict
from re import findall
from itertools import combinations

def nest():
  return defaultdict(nest)

d = nest()
row_to_key = nest()

with open('table.csv') as f:
  for idx, line in enumerate(f):
    indices = [idx for idx, i in enumerate(findall(r'[^,]+', line)) \
      if i == 'TRUE']
    for j, k, l, m in combinations(indices, 4):
      if not d[j][k][l][m]:
        d[j][k][l][m] = idx
        row_to_key[idx] = [j, k, l, m]
      break

for row_idx in row_to_key:
  print(' * row number', row_idx, 'can be identified by cols', row_to_key[row_idx])
```

This will output:

```
 * row number 1 can be identified by cols [2, 5, 7, 10]
 * row number 2 can be identified by cols [0, 9, 10, 12]
 * row number 3 can be identified by cols [3, 4, 5, 9]
 * row number 4 can be identified by cols [0, 4, 5, 7]
...
```

Comment: oh, I got your point. but it's my fault to make your misunderstanding the primary key. You identify each row with unique a column combinations. Great job! But the [primary keys](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primary_key) I need have to come from same columns. Anyway,your answer is very inspiring, thank you again!

Comment: Hmm, I still find it quite unclear what you're after (a composite primary key?), but it sounds like you have a way forward so good luck