# How to find all possible column sets as primary key & foreign key candidates in two CSV files?

Tags: python, sql, sql-server, pandas, python-itertools

I have 2 CSV files, PAYMENT and CUSTOMER (not normalized, example, real files up to 100 columns each):

```
ID, CUST_NAME, CUST_NUM, CLIENT_NAME, PAYMENT_NUM, START_DATE,  END_DATE
1,     CUST1,   A001,    CLIENT1,       10,        2018-04-01, 2018-04-02
2,     CUST1,   A001,    CLIENT1,       10,        2018-04-01, 2018-05-30
3,     CUST2,   A002,    CLIENT1,      101,        2018-04-02, 2018-04-03
4,     CUST2,   A002,    CLIENT1,      102,        2018-04-02, 2018-04-03
```

```
ID, CUST_NAME, CUST_NUM, AGE, GENDER, COUNTRY
1,     CUST1,   A001,     32,   M,       US
2,     CUST2,   A002,     34,   F,       CA
3,     CUST3,   A003,     45,   M,       US
4,     CUST4,   A004,     31,   F,       CA
```

How to find all possible column sets as primary key & foreign key candidates in two CSV files?

Desired output:

1. CUSTOMER.CUST_NAME (PK), PAYMENT.CUST_NAME (FK)
2. CUSTOMER.CUST_NUM (PK), PAYMENT.CUST_NUM (FK)
3. CUSTOMER.CUST_NAME (PK), CUSTOMER.CUST_NUM (PK), PAYMENT.CUST_NAME (FK), PAYMENT.CUST_NUM (FK)

I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49998457/how-to-find-a-columns-set-for-a-primary-key-candidate-in-csv-file) use pandas and itertools to solve the first part of question for primary key. How to further solve the second part of finding foreign keys and then match them?

Comment: Have a look at `CROSS JOIN` (and `DISTINCT`).

Answer (score 0):

try to iterate through all combinations generated from `itertools.product()` method. Use `df.isin()` in order to check to see if the values in the first csv's columns are present in the corresponding column of the second csv file.To be able to match them use `merge()`function from Pandas library.